# Compact way to store local javascript with table data?

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects

I generate HTML reports for offline use, basically as PDFs with added interactivity. As a part of this I need to load in large amounts of tabular data. The format as used by my functions is row-major encoding. Given that Chrome and other browsers generally forbid direct loading of data from disk I have to use a workaround whereby I store it in a `data.js` file and `src` it into my html as follows

index.html:

```
...
<script src="./data.js"></>
...
```

data.js:

```
var data = [
    {"Petal.Length":1.4,"Petal.Width":0.2,"Species":"setosa"},
    {"Petal.Length":1.4,"Petal.Width":0.2,"Species":"setosa"},
    {"Petal.Length":1.3,"Petal.Width":0.2,"Species":"setosa"},
    {"Petal.Length":1.5,"Petal.Width":0.2,"Species":"setosa"}
]
```

These get to be around 100mb+ for the data I'm using so I've made a small optimisation in changing it to column-major notation with a transform in JavaScript to switch it back i.e.

```
var data = {
    "Petal.Length":[1.4,1.4,1.3,1.5],
    "Petal.Width":[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2],
    "Species":["setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa"]
}
data = toRowMajor(data)
```

However I am wondering if there are further (relatively lightweight) ways to save space on my data.

Comment: Presumably the `"Species"` names don't contain quotation marks, so instead of an array of strings you could use a single string of comma-separated values like `Species: "setosa,setosa,setosa,setosa"` to save on a whole bunch of quotation mark characters. (I'm assuming your real data has a much longer list, such that removing quotation marks would make a difference.)

Comment: We need more informations about your data structure.. For those kind of questions it always depends. For instance if there are a few number of species, just put the names in a short array and only store the index in the species json.

Comment: My actual data is a gene annotation table. Each row is a gene and columns are "GeneID", "GeneSymbol", "Description", "Chromosome", "Expression", "LogFoldChange", "PValue". The indexing trick may work on Chromosome but all other columns contain mostly unique values. My other data is a matrix of gene expressions, with 300+ columns and 10000+ rows of floats.